# ASM/OPcode injection with C++

Tags: c++, dll, assembly, code-injection

I'm trying to inject some ASM code into a Win32 program with C++.
Is there a way to do this, avoiding DLL injection ?

This, for instance :

```
__asm{}
```

is only for the current program. Is there something similar used to generate hex code I could inject with WriteProcessMemory ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You mean you want an inline assembler, or write executable code to runtime memory, or else?

Comment: I want to write executable code into another program memory

Comment: The fact that you use C++ matters very little in this case. It could be C, Pascal or most anything.

Comment: Why in the world do you need to do this for? I will not be a happy camper with your program messing around with my programs' executable code!

Comment: Yes but for the injection, I use the C++ function WriteProcessMemory. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx . Maybe there were a trick to make my asm code compiled and ready for injection :S

Comment: In silico, oh, just a proof of concept to create something like a game-trainers (nothing bad, i swear :P )

Comment: This is a hacking technique - which can be used for good, evil or just plain mundane, like most other programming techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MSVC it may look like this:

```
        void* shellcodeStart;
        void* shellcodeEnd;
        __asm {
                mov shellcodeStart, offset shellcode_start
                mov shellcodeEnd, offset shellcode_end
                jmp shellcode_end
shellcode_start:
                ... // your code
shellcode_end:
        }
        size_t cb = shellcodeEnd - shellcodeStart;
        WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, remoteAddress, shellcodeStart, cb, NULL);
```

Comment: But, it's for the current program not for the aimed program ?

Answer (score 1):

One technique is to hand-assembly and put the code in an array, then copy the code where it should go. But this is straying into hacking land which I don't know much about.

Comment: Yes, I was doing like this before, but I was looking for something more flexible :) thx